# Should I use a finalize method with an IDisposable class containing a TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext, idisposable, transactionscope

I've written a class which pairs up a `TransactionScope` with an Linq to Sql `DataContext`.

It implements the same methods as the `TransactionScope`, `Dispose()` and `Complete()` and exposes the DataContext.

It's purpose is to ensure that DataContexts are not re-used, they are paired up with a single transaction and Disposed along with it.

Should I include a Finalize method in the class? One that calls Dispose if it has not already been called? Or it that only for IDisposables that reference unmanaged resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, **never** implement a finaliser in a class that is disposable just because it wraps a disposable class.

Consider that you have three clean-up scenarios for a class with `Dispose` and a finaliser:

1. `Dispose()` is called.
2. The finaliser is called on application shutdown.
3. The object was going to be collected, but the finaliser hadn't been suppressed (most often from a call to `Dispose()`, but note that you should always suppress your finaliser when anything puts it in a state where it doesn't need to be cleaned up, and re-registered if it is put in a state where it does need it - e.g. if you had an `Open()`/`Close()` pair of methods).

Now, if you are directly managing an unmanaged resource (e.g. a handle through an `IntPtr`), these three of these scenarios where you will have one of the two clean-up methods called directly match the three scenarios where you need clean-up to happen.

Okay. So, let's consider a disposable wrapping a disposable where the "outer" class has a finaliser implemented correctly:

```
~MyClass()
{
  // This space deliberately left blank.
}
```

The finaliser doesn't do anything, because there's no unmanaged clean-up for it to handle. The only effect is that if this null finaliser hasn't been suppressed, then upon garbage collection it will be put in the finaliser queue - keeping it and anything only reachable through it's fields alive and promoting them to the next generation - and eventually the finalisation thread will call this nop method, mark it as having been finalised and it becomes eligible for garbage collection again. But since it was promoted it'll be Gen 1 if it had been Gen 0, and Gen 2 if it had been Gen 1.

The actual object that did need to be finalised will also be promoted, and it'll have to wait that bit longer not just for collection, but also for finalisation. It's going to end up in Gen 2 no matter what.

Okay, that's bad enough, let's say we actually put some code in the finaliser that did something with the field that holds the finalisable class.

Wait. What are we going to do? We can't call a finaliser directly, so we dispose it. Oh wait, are we sure that for this class the behaviour of `Dispose()` and that of the finaliser is close enough that it's safe? How do we know it doesn't hold onto some resources via weak-references that it will try to deal with in the dispose method and not in the finaliser? The author of that class knows all about the perils of dealing with weak-references from within a finaliser, but they thought they were writing a `Dispose()` method, not part of someone else's finaliser method.

And then, what if the outer finaliser was called during application shut-down. How do you know the inner finaliser wasn't already called? When the author of the class was writing their `Dispose()` method, are they sure to ponder "okay, now let's make sure I handle the case of this being called after the finaliser has already run and the only thing left for this object to do is have it's memory freed?" Not really. It might be that they guarded against repeated calls to `Dispose()` in such a way that also protects from this scenario, but you can't really bet on it (especially since they won't be helping that in the finaliser which they know will be the last method ever called and any other sort of cleanup like nulling fields that won't be used again to flag them as such, is pointless). It could end up doing something like dropping the reference count of some reference-counted resource, or otherwise violating the contract of the unmanaged code it is its job to deal with.

So. Best case scenario with a finaliser in such a class is that you damage the efficiency of garbage collection, and worse-case is you have a bug which interfere with the perfectly good clean-up code you were trying to help.

Note also the logic behind the pattern MS used to promote (and still have in some of their classes) where you have a protected `Dispose(bool disposing)` method. Now, I have a lot of bad things to say about this pattern, but when you look at it, it is designed to deal with the very fact that what you clean up with `Dispose()` and what you clean up in a finaliser are not the same - the pattern means that an object's directly-held unmanaged resources will be cleaned up in both cases (in the scenario of your question, there are no such resources) and that managed resources such as an internally-held `IDisposable` object are cleaned-up **only** from `Dispose()`, and not from a finaliser.

Implement `IDisposable.Dispose()` if you have **anything** that needs to be cleaned up, whether an unmanaged resource, an object that is `IDisposable` or anything else.

Write a finaliser if, and only if you **directly** have an unmanaged resource that needs to be cleaned up, and make cleaning it up the **only** thing you do there.

For bonus points, avoid being in both classes at once - wrap all unmanaged resources in disposable and finalisable classes that only deal with that unmanaged classes, and if you need to combine that functionality with other resources do it in a disposable-only class that uses such classes. That way clean-up will be clearer, simpler, less prone to bugs, and less damaging to GC efficiency (no risk of finalisation of one object delaying that of another).

Answer (score 3):

A Finalizer is meant solely for cleaning up unmanaged resources. There is no use in calling the dispose of dependent object inside the finalizer, since if those objects manage critical resources, they have a finalizer by them selves.

In .NET 2.0 and up there is even less reason to implement a finalizer, no .NET contains the [SafeHandle](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396335.aspx) class.

However, one reason I sometimes find to still implement a finalizer, is to find out whether developers forgot to call Dispose. I let this class implement the finalizer only in the debug build and let it write to the Debug window.

Comment: +1 That is a good exception, and I've done it myself. It doesn't cause finalisation bugs and the damage to performance is fine in debug runs.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple answer for this one - it is debatable.

#### What?

The debate is whether to use finaliser with a full *Disposable* pattern. Your code use transactions and database context - those guys (usually) use unmanaged resources (like kernel transaction objects and TCP/IP connections)

#### Why?

If you use any unmanaged resource that should be cleaned up, you should implement `IDisposable`. Then a client code can wrap a call to the class into the recommended `using(IDisposable myClass = new MyClass(){...}` construct. The problem is if a developer wouldn't call `IDisposable.Dispose()` explicitly or implicitly, then the resource wouldn't be free up automatically. Even if the object `myClass` has been collected by GC. This is because GC never calls `Dispose` during collection, it's the responsibility of finilisation queue.

Thus you can define a finiliser, that will eventually be called by GC finilisation thread, that is independent from garbage collection.

#### Opinions

Some people argue that you should just make sure you put all the *disposable* code into `using (){}` and forget about finilisation. After all you must release such resources ASAP and the whole finalisation process is kinda vague for many developers.

In contrast, I prefer to explicitly implement finilisator, simply because I don't know who will use my code. So if someone forgets to call a `Dispose` on the class that requires that, the resource will eventually be released.

#### Conclusion

Personally, I would recommend to implement finilisator with any class that implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: They don't have any unmanaged resources, so what should the finaliser do?

Comment: @JonHanna transaction scope usually use kernel transaction object and data context hold sql connections. Those underlying internal objects do use unmanaged resources.

Comment: Yes, but they're not implementing `TransactionScope`, they're implementing a wrapper around `TransactionScope`. `TransactionScope` itself is an managed resource, whether it holds unmanaged or not, and it's finaliser will be called if necessary. At best you just delay it's finalisation and collection, at worse you introduce a bug (Actually, `TransactionScope` doesn't directly hold unmanaged resources either, and doesn't have a finaliser for precisely the same reason - never have a finaliser in a class that doesn't *directly* hold an unmanaged resources).

Comment: Similarly, `DataContext` has quite a large graph of disposable objects that don't have finalisers, until you get to `SQLConnection` which inherits one, but suppresses it on construction as it is never needed, which has an internal object (if it's open) and *that* has a finaliser because that has an unmanaged resource. Any of those other classes dealing with it during finalisation would again at best slow things down, and could introduce a bug.